# Find column from event was fired

Tags: lightning-web-components, button, lightning-datatable, action, column

experts! I have LWC data table populated with data. One or more columns contain Button element. I want to show some 'master-detail' information by clicking this button.

I tried to handle `onRowAction` but only I can see is `e.detail.row` with contents of whole row. How can I get number (or something else about) of column from where event was fired? Or I have to use some another event for this?

Comment: seems to I have to use typeAttributes: {name: 'whatEverIWant'} for the Button and then make a desicion on e.detail.action.name